# Building maven project fails on invalid target version 17.0.5

Tags: java, maven, java-11, java-17

I am upgrading application from Java 11 to Java 17.0.5

In my java project, I have set below properties

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17.0.5</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17.0.5</maven.compiler.target>  
      <java.version>17.0.5<java.version>                                            
</properties>
```

On building the project, it failed saying

> invalid target release 17.0.5

`java -version` prints

> "Java version 17.0.5"

and `mvn -version` prints

> Java 17.0.5

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

The version is only the major version. So you have to specify only 17 as version

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>  
    <java.version>17<java.version>                                            
</properties>
```

Comment: Will this pick Jdk 17.0.5? Trying to understand how it works internally

Comment: It doesn't pickup any version. It uses the jdk which is configured by maven. normally the version is specified in the PATH variable. This configuration only told maven for which java version the code should be compiled. You can also use a JDK 17 and specify `java.version` to 11

Comment: when i ran mvn version it prints Java Version 17.0.5. that means 17.0.5 will be picked?

Comment: Yes but it has nothing to do with the `java.version` tag

Comment: my is a spring boot application, should I set java.version to 17.0.5..I am a little confused on difference between the maven complier complier and java.version and which to use when. Setting java.version to 17.0.5 and maven source and target to 17 as below, builds project successfully  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>  
      <java.version>17.0.5<java.version>                                            
</properties>

Comment: as I know `java.version` is a shortcut for `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`.`<java.version>17.0.5</java.version>` is just invalid

Comment: if I just used java.version and set it <java.version>17<java.version> , will this use 17.0.5 or exact 17? I want the app to use 17.0.5

Comment: It will use the JVM which is in your $PATH variable. Also if you set any other valid value